# positive group homomorphism from a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is a positive scalar multiple.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider a subgroup of the real number (additive subgroup) and a positive homomorphism $\tau$ from the subgroup to $\mathbb R$. Positive homomorphism means it maps positive elements to positive elements. I believe that  $\tau$ has to be a positive scalar multiple ie $\tau(x)=cx$ but I am not sure how to show this. This is easy if we are looking at a positive homomorphism from $R$ to $R$ since we can show that $\tau$ maps every element to the scalar multiple of $\tau(1)$ and then we inductively show this for the integers, rational numbers, and real numbers. However an additive subgroup of $R$ may not contain the integers and it may not even contain $1$. So how should I show this?

Comment: Why is it clear in the $\mathbb{R}$ case?  Your argument seems to use scalar multiples, which you don’t have.  See, for instance, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234954/discontinuous-homomorphism-from-bbb-r-to-bbb-r), which describes a construction for a group homomorphism which is not continuous.  It may be the case that only scalar multiples are possible, but more care may be needed.

Comment: $\tau(1)$ isn't even necessarily defined, unless $1$ is in your subgroup.

Comment: If the subgroup is discrete, then it is cyclic, and thus $\ta$ has your property. Otherwise the subgroup is dense everywhere, and has the property that I f $a<b$ then $\tau(a)<\tau(b),$ This would seem to make $\tau$ continuous. That seems like a good starting place.